# Get Lon Lat values from a GEOGRAPHY data type in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql

After storing lon lat values as a GEOGRAPHY data type, how do I retrieve the individual lat lon values?

**Failed attempt:**

```
SELECT id, geog, ST_X(geog), ST_Y(geog) FROM locations;
```

**Error:**

```
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: For *geography* datatype use valid function, ex. *ST_MaxX()* and  *ST_MaxY()*.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [ST_X(point)](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_X.html) function only supports the geometry (as for now).

One workaround is to [cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) the geog to geom using `::geometry`.

Hense your query should be like this:

```
SELECT id, geog, ST_X(geog::geometry), ST_Y(geog::geometry) FROM locations;
```

And since it's geog the SRID would be [4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/).

Also [here's](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geography.html#casting-to-geometry) a good source for the geog type.

Comment: Thanks your solution works well (when querying using pgAdmin3). However when I am querying from PHP (nginx + php5-fpm), I get the error: `Undefined object: 7 ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist`. Any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780931/postgresql-query-error-when-using-pdo-driver-in-php-laravel-4

Comment: Good, it works well for me.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to share the query with my client. You saved my another day

Answer (score 1):

### Not need cast

Try to use this query.

```
SELECT ST_XMax(geog), ST_YMax(geog), ST_AsEWKT(geog)
FROM locations LIMIT 10;
```

it works for me.

Comment: What PostGIS & PostgreSQL version are you using? With 9.5 and 2.2, running the query `SELECT ST_XMax(ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-73.968504 40.779741)'));` gives me `ERROR:  function st_xmax(geography) does not exist`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this query.

```
SELECT X(the_geom), Y(the_geom), ST_AsEWKT(the_geom)
      FROM locations LIMIT 10;
```

i hope it helps you

Comment: The `X()` and `Y()` functions don't seem to exist. Where did you get those?

Comment: @Zoltán I think `X()` and `Y()` are valid in an older revision of PostGIS--perhaps 8.x?. Updated, that query would use `ST_X()` and `ST_Y()` instead.

Comment: Even PostGIS 2.2 have no ST_X(*geography* ), see http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/ST_X.html