# Extract lat/long from native PostgeSQL point type column

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry-data-type

In my table I have a column `location` that is a [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-geometric.html). I tried this:

```
SELECT ST_X(location), ST_Y(location) FROM locations;
```

But I still get the error message:

```
ERROR: function st_x(point) does not exist
```

Comment: If you execute the query `SELECT ST_X(ST_GeomFromEWKT('POINT(1 2 3 4)'));` does it work or get any error?

Comment: it returns "1". I have the postgis extension added

Comment: what do you get from "\d locations" and "select * from locations"? paste here the first 5 lines of the latter query

Comment: The best answer is here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57020

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your column `location` type is `point` ([PostgreSQL reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-geometric.html)). This is a native PostgreSQL type, not an Postgis datatype.

You have to change `location` column data type to `geometry` or add a new geometry column with the Postgis function [`AddGeometryColumn`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html).

Comment: `AddGeometryColumn` is dated now you can just `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN`

Answer (score 16):

you need to use:

```
SELECT ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom) FROM locations;
```

I suppose that locations is a table of points with the geometry named as "geom".

Hope this helps,

Comment: `Property Value Name location Position 35 Data type point Collation Default Sequence Not NULL? No Primary key? No Foreign key? No Storage PLAIN Inherited No Statistics -1 System column? No` I don't understand what you mean with this comment

Comment: my "location" column field table properties...I dont know how to edit this nicely :(

Answer (score 10):

None of these talk about how to extract lat/long with the native point type. Clearly you can't use `ST_X()` and `ST_Y` like you can do with a PostGIS Geometery; so here with the native point simply use array-deference syntax `[0]` and `[1]`. For example, if you have a native type and you want to go to PostGIS type you can [do it like this (from my answer on dba.se).](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156948/2639)

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(p[0],p[1])
FROM ( VALUES (point(-71.1043443253471,42.3150676015829)) ) AS t(p);
```

Comment: This helped me because I was looking for Postgres native solution

Answer (score 5):

You can treat the point type like an array to access the x and y components like this:

```
SELECT location[0], location[1] FROM locations;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer:

```
SELECT ST_X(location::geometry), ST_Y(location::geometry) FROM locations;
```

Comment: Thanks for a straight working solution